# How to programmatically check if the current sharepoint user name and password?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model, authentication

[image]

Hi,
i am using client object model in c# win form. How to programmatically check if the current SharePoint user name and password is correct?

here I log in using SharePoint Site URL, username and Password. if User name or Password is Wrong then Log-in Process will be cancelled. how can i do this??

Comment: The screenshot of your login dialog is not useful, but code of what you've tried so far would be.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you mean a SharePoint 2010 forms authentication site where userid and password are to be provided. Check the code snippet below - you'll have to check exception value 
 below and handle the exception accordingly (cancel login, etc). See the [FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.formsauthenticationlogininfo) for more info.

```
try {
ClientContext fooCtx = new ClientContext(fooSiteUrl); 
fooCtx.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.FormsAuthentication; 
fooCtx.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo = new FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo(fooUserName, fooUserPwd); 
}
catch (Exception fooE) {... }
...
```